# Absolutely positioned element within horizontally floated containers?

Tags: css

I want to horizontally position some text along with two dropdown menus like:

```
Text One : | I'm a dropdown |     Text Two: | I'm a second dropdown |
```

where the 'I'm a dropdown' elements are absolutely positioned `ul` elements and will eventually have some JS to act as dropdown menus. I initially thought the HTML would be something like [(Here is the JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/cvZfF/4/):

```html
<div id="wrapper" class="clearfix">
    <div>
        Tet One
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <ul>
            <li>I'm a dropdown</li>
            <li>Value One</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        Text Two
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <ul>
            <li>I'm a second dropdown</li>
            <li>Value Two</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

along with CSS like:

```css
#wrapper > div{
    float: left;
}
#wrapper > div.dropdown{
    position: relative;
}
#wrapper > div > ul{
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The result is that the text-only `div` elements ('Text One' and 'Text Two') float fine, but the relatively positioned elements don't maintain a proper width and the absolutely positioned `ul` elements are placed on top of each other, i.e. everything is squished to the left.

a) can this be fixed?

b) is this the wrong approach and is there a better one (like using `display: inline-block`?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by using an `inline-block` outter div, placed each absolutely positioned ul inside a relative div wrapper like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/timmyomahony/tGn6m/

On reflection, I didn't ask this question very well so apologies for those who took the time to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Made some enhancements
http://jsfiddle.net/cvZfF/74/

---

This one's for starters

http://jsfiddle.net/cvZfF/56/

You need all content to be position relative, not absolute;
OnClick clone the UL with JavaScript (jQuery in my case) and show it at the position of the original. The rest is up to you.